# Is it possible to suppress 'Out[xxx]=' without suppressing 'In[xxx]:='?

Tags: customization, interface

While I have not exhaustively searched [`Help/Documentation Center`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/Mathematica.html) for an answer to my question, I have put forth a yeoman's effort without any success.

Does anyone know if it is possible to suppress `Out=` on an on-going basis within a notebook without also suppressing `In:=` and if it is, could you please tell me how?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!  Instead of signing the post, please set a display name.  user12345-style names are not easy to remember.

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 11):

1. Go to Format -> Edit Stylesheet
2. Under "Choose a style" choose "Output"
3. Select the cell bracket of the new cell that appears
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> on a Mac) to show the cell expression
5. Change `Cell[StyleData["Output"]]` to `Cell[StyleData["Output"], ShowCellLabel -> False]`
6. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> again
7. Close the stylesheet window